# Pattern Check for a specific string Required

Tags: regex

I want to validate every string in text file. The contents in each row are separated by tab.

**Data Format**:

```
EmployeeNumber {tab} EmployeeName {tab} Age {tab} IsCurrentlyEmployed

Sample text:

E001 {tab} Jim Watson {tab} 35 {tab} Yes

E002 {tab} Mark Smith {tab} 50 {tab} No
```

So I am guessing the check should be

```
(AlphaNumeric String){tab}(Normal String){tab}(Number){tab}(Yes/No)
```

Thank you

Comment: The check you provided would be correct, and you would be able to validate using that as a regex. What exactly is your question though? Whether it would work? If there is a more specific regex to validate it against? What are you asking?

Comment: I wanted help with the exact RegEx expression

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `regex` like this that matches the pattern you have provided:

```
\w+\t[a-zA-Z\s]+\t\d{1,3}\t(Yes|No)
```

matches:

```
E001    Jim Watson  35  Yes //where blanks are tabs.
```

Walkthrough of the steps:

```
\w  -> Matches any word character (equal to [a-zA-Z0-9_])
+   -> Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible 
\t  -> Matches a tab character
[a-zA-Z\s]+  ->  Matches entire alphabet, upper/lower case and spaces between one and unlimited times
\t  -> Matches a tab character
\d{1,3}  ->  Matches any digit between 1-3 times (age 1-100+)
\t  -> Matches a tab character
(Yes|No)  -> Matches string "Yes" or "No" (it will break if string is "yes" or "no").
```

Comment: Thank you, the walk-through steps were very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If it needs to be in that **exact** format you provided, you could use

```
E\d+\t[A-Za-z] [A-Za-z]\t\d+\t(?:Yes|No)
```

That `regex` would match the following

```
E015 {Tab} John Doe {Tab} 32 {Tab} Yes
E451 {Tab} Jane Doe {Tab} 25 {Tab} No
```

but not the following

```
015 {Tab} John Doe {Tab} 32 {Tab} Yes # the E at the beginning is missing
E451 {Tab} Jane {Tab} 32 {Tab} No # only the first name is given
E {Tab} Johnson Doe {Tab} 48 {Tab} Yes # no employee number provided
```

If you are looking for a less-strict regex, use the one provided in `demogorgon.net`'s answer